# Carbon/Carbon.h won't precompile moving from SDK 4 to SDK 5

Tags: xcode, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to update an older Mac app which is being built with SDK 4. When I change it to SDK 5 in the project settings, compilation fails doing just the Carbon/Carbon.h file. It comes back with **LP64** is not defined, MATH64_USE_INLINE is not defined and so on.

There must be a project setting that I am missing since the compiler never even gets to any code in the project, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple did not create a 64-bit version of the Carbon API. Make sure you only compile for 32bit in project settings.

Follow this guide:
[64-Bit Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/intro/intro.html)

And:
[64-Bit Guide for Carbon Developers](http://www.filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/Carbon64BitGuide.pdf)

Comment: It was set for 32bit in the project, but I also had to edit the active target settings. Many thanks!